# Handlebars, if you select a user from the select tag to add the appropriate values in the div tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, sequelize.js

please tell me I from a database insert the values using the handlebars to the tag to select, according to the value of two div to pass other values(for example: selecting the name, you need to pass the name and surname corresponding with the names) my stack is nodejs, handlebars, MySQL and sequelize 
my code user.js:

```
});

return User;
}
```

controller.js:

```
exports.users = function (req, res) {

db.user.findAll({
    fio: 'fio ASC'

}).then(function (data) {
    var hbsObject = {
        users: data
    };
    res.render('users', hbsObject);


});
```

user.hbs:

```
<label for="users">users:</label>
<select name="users">
    {{#each users}}
        <option  value={{this.id}}>{{this.fio}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select><br>
```

In the last two div you want to show the Name and lastname of the selected user in the select tag. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: As a quick check, log `data`, e.g. `console.log('data: ', data)`, to ensure you're actually returning an object. This also lets you look at the data structure. As written, you assume `data` will be an array instead of `'key': []`, or some other structure. I suspect that's your issue.

Comment: @rmharrison in the console I brought, I can't figure out when I in tag select selected user how do I apply to the data that is to his name, and not to all user names

Comment: In practice, `findAll()` will probably return more than one user, as it searches for all instances that match your criteria, in this case just `fio`. For one user, `findOne()` or `findById()` are more appropriate. That said, iterating over `users` doesn't make much sense if you're only using find to return a single user.